# Can we deduce that $0<a<ψ_{k}$ for infinitely many $k$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(ψ_{k})_{k≥1}$ be a bounded, positive and strictely decreasing real sequence ($ψ_{k}>ψ_{k+1}$), then it converges to its greatest lower bound $a>0$.

My **question** is: Can we deduce that $$0<a<ψ_{k}$$ for infinitely many $k$.

Comment: *Strictly* decreasing?

Comment: Does "decreasing" mean $\psi_{k+1} \leqslant \psi_k$ or $\psi_{k+1} < \psi_k$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: It is the first case.

Comment: In that case, consider a constant sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer: No, I am wrong, the exercice say that the sequence is strictely decreasing. Sorry for that error.

Comment: In that case, suppose you have $\psi_m \leqslant a$. What follows for $\psi_{m+1}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: We get $ψ_{k+1}<ψ_{k}<a$.

Comment: And how does that align with the premises?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Here where I am not able to continue  when using a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we can deduce $\psi_k > a$ for **all** $k$. For if there were an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\psi_m \leqslant a$, then by the strict monotonicity we'd have

$$\psi_{m+1} < \psi_m \leqslant a,$$

and thus $a$ would not be a lower bound of $\{\psi_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, contrary to the premises.

---

With a direct argument: Since $a$ is a lower bound, it follows that

$$\psi_k > \psi_{k+1} \geqslant a$$

for all $k$.